# Openpyxl and Binary Search

Tags: python, optimization, openpyxl

The problem: I have two spreadsheets. Spreadsheet 1 has about 20,000 rows. Spreadsheet 2 has near 1 million rows. When a value from a row in spreadsheet 1 matches a value from a row in spreadsheet 2, the entire row from spreadsheet 2 is written to excel. The problem isn't too difficult, but with such a large number of rows, the run time is incredibly long.

Book 1 Example:
|Key   |Value             |
|------|------------------|
|397241|587727227839578000|

An example of book 2:

| ID | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 587727227839578000 | 393 | 24 | 0.43 |

My current solution is:

```
g1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('path/to/sheet/sheet1.xlsx',read_only=True)
grid1 = g1.active
grid1_rows = list(grid1.rows)

g2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('path/to/sheet2/sheet2.xlsx',read_only=True)
grid2 = g2.active
grid2_rows = list(grid2.rows)

for row in grid1_rows:
        value1 = int(row[1].value)
        print(value1)
        for row2 in grid2_rows:
            value2 = int(row2[0].value)
            if value1 == value2:
                new_Name = int(row[0].value)
                print("match")
                output_file.write(str(new_Name))
                output_file.write(",")
                output_file.write(",".join(str(c.value) for c in row2[1:]))
                output_file.write("\n")
```

This solution works, but again the runtime is absurd. Ideally I'd like to take value1 (which comes from the first sheet,) then perform a binary search for that value on the other sheet, then just like my current solution, if it matches, copy the entire row to a new file. then just

If there's an even faster method to do this I'm all ears. I'm not the greatest at python so any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting your butt kicked here because you are using an inappropriate data structure, which requires you to use the nested loop.

The below example uses *sets* to match indices from first sheet to those in the second sheet.  This *assumes* there are no duplicates on either sheet, which would seem weird given your problem description.  Once we make sets of the indices from both sheets, all we need to do is intersect the 2 sets to find the ones that are on sheet 2.

Then we have the matches, but we can do better.  If we put the second sheet row data into dictionary with the indices as the keys, then we can hold onto the row data while we do the match, rather than have to go hunting for the matching indices after intersecting the sets.

I've also put in an enumeration, which may or may not be needed to identify which rows in the spreadsheet are the ones of interest.  Probably not needed.

This should execute in the blink of an eye after things are loaded.  If you start to have memory issues, you may want to just construct the dictionary at the start rather than the list *and* the dictionary.

#### Book 1:

[image]

#### Book 2:

[image]

#### Code:

```
import openpyxl

g1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx',read_only=True)
grid1 = g1.active
grid1_rows = list(grid1.rows)[1:]  # exclude the header

g2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book2.xlsx',read_only=True)
grid2 = g2.active
grid2_rows = list(grid2.rows)[1:]  # exclude the header

# make a set of the values in Book 1 that we want to search for...

search_items = {int(t[0].value) for t in grid1_rows}
#print(search_items)

# make a dictionary (key-value paring) for the items in the 2nd book, and
# include an enumeration so we can capture the row number

lookup_dict = {int(t[0].value) : (idx, t) for idx,t in enumerate(grid2_rows, start=1)}

#print(lookup_dict)

# now let's intersect the set of search items and key values to get the keys of the matches...

keys = search_items & lookup_dict.keys()

#print(keys)

for key in keys:
    idx = lookup_dict.get(key)[0]       # the row index, if needed
    row_data = lookup_dict.get(key)[1]  # the row data
    print(f'row {idx} matched value {key} and has data:')
    print(f'  name: {row_data[1].value:10s} \t qty: {int(row_data[2].value)}')
```

#### Output:

```
row 3 matched value 202 and has data:
  name: steak        qty: 3
row 1 matched value 455 and has data:
  name: dogfood      qty: 10
```

Comment: Thanks @AirSquid , this is definitely faster. However I'm now getting the following:
```Unknown format code 's' for object of type 'int'```

I added an example of the type of data I'm working with in the post.

Comment: Nevermind, think I figured it out.